# как двигать в реальном времени view объекты?

Tags: java, android

например двигать textView каждую секунду на пиксель на право. это не должно быть анимацией.
я хочу попробовать сделать игру в android stduio но из не знаний не умею двигать объекты

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например вот так

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var tv: TextView
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        tv = findViewById(R.id.tv)
        Timer().schedule(MyTimerTask(), 1000, 1000)
    }

    inner class MyTimerTask : TimerTask() {
        override fun run() {
            runOnUiThread { tv.x = tv.x + 1 }
        }
    }
}
```